# Docusign single signer but multiple signatures on document

Tags: php, docusignapi

I am using Docusign php api. I am signing the document by this api . everything is fine . But now i need signatures of recipients at multiple places. I don't know how many times i need the signature , Even i don't know the position where i need the signature tab , I just have a placeholder in the html doc and that is #\b . I have to put signature tab where is #\b

```
// create a new DocuSign configuration and assign host and header(s)
    $config = new DocuSign\eSign\Configuration();
    $config->setHost($host);
    $config->addDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", "{\"Username\":\"" . $username . "\",\"Password\":\"" . $password . "\",\"IntegratorKey\":\"" . $integrator_key . "\"}");
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // STEP 1:  Login() API
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // instantiate a new docusign api client
    $apiClient = new DocuSign\eSign\ApiClient($config);
    // we will first make the Login() call which exists in the AuthenticationApi...
    $authenticationApi = new DocuSign\eSign\Api\AuthenticationApi($apiClient);
    // optional login parameters
    $options = new \DocuSign\eSign\Api\AuthenticationApi\LoginOptions();
    // call the login() API
    $loginInformation = $authenticationApi->login($options);
    // parse the login results
    if(isset($loginInformation) && count($loginInformation) > 0)
    {
        // note: defaulting to first account found, user might be a 
        // member of multiple accounts
        $loginAccount = $loginInformation->getLoginAccounts()[0];
        if(isset($loginInformation))
        {
            $accountId = $loginAccount->getAccountId();
        }
    }
    if(empty($accountId))
    {
        return false;
    }
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // STEP 2:  Create & Send Envelope (aka Signature Request)
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // set recipient information

    // instantiate a new envelopeApi object
    $envelopeApi = new DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi($apiClient);
    // Add a document to the envelope
    $document = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Document();
    $document->setDocumentBase64(base64_encode(file_get_contents($documentFileName)));
    $document->setName($documentName);
    $document->setDocumentId("1");
    // Create a |SignHere| tab somewhere on the document for the recipient to sign
    $signHere = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere();
    $signHere->setXPosition("20");
    $signHere->setYPosition("20");
    $signHere->setDocumentId("1");
    $signHere->setPageNumber("1");
    $signHere->setRecipientId("1");

   // add the signature tab to the envelope's list of tabs
    $tabs = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs();
    $tabs->setSignHereTabs(array($signHere));
    // add a signer to the envelope
    $signer = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Signer();
    $signer->setEmail($recipientEmail);
    $signer->setName($recipientName);
    $signer->setRecipientId("1");
    $signer->setClientUserId('12345');
    $signer->setTabs($tabs);
    // Add a recipient to sign the document
    $recipients = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Recipients();
    $recipients->setSigners(array($signer));
    $envelop_definition = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition();
    $envelop_definition->setEmailSubject("Please sign this doc");
    // set envelope status to "sent" to immediately send the signature request
    $envelop_definition->setStatus("sent");
    $envelop_definition->setRecipients($recipients);
    $envelop_definition->setDocuments(array($document));
    // create and send the envelope! (aka signature request)
    $envelop_summary = $envelopeApi->createEnvelope($accountId, $envelop_definition, null);
    if($envelop_summary)
    {
        $document=json_decode($envelop_summary);
        $envloped=$document->envelopeId;
        // get the document url 
        $ReturnUrl=add_query_arg(array('action'=>'docusign_request','_uid'=>$formprocess,'_envelopid'=>$envloped),get_permalink());

        $viewrequest = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientViewRequest();
        $viewrequest->setUserName($recipientName); 
        $viewrequest->setEmail($recipientEmail);
        $viewrequest->setRecipientId(1);
        $viewrequest->setClientUserId('12345');
        $viewrequest->setAuthenticationMethod('email');
        $viewrequest->setReturnUrl($ReturnUrl);
        $envelopview=$envelopeApi->createRecipientView($accountId,$document->envelopeId,$viewrequest);
        $redirecturl=$envelopview->getUrl();
        wp_redirect($redirecturl);
        // get the doc url
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Docusign Anchor tabs for this purpose

https://github.com/docusign/docusign-soap-sdk/wiki/Code-Walkthrough-_-Anchor-Tabs

> Anchor Tabs are a solution for this. Since an Anchor Tab works by matching a string that is present in the document’s text, we would just need to examine the document and see if there is a suitable bit of text. Many contracts have something like “Sign Here” printed on the document, so we could use that as the anchor text, and then DocuSign would place a Signature Tab on the document everywhere it finds the text “Sign Here”.

```
// Create a |SignHere| tab somewhere on the document for the recipient to sign
$signHere = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere();
$signHere->setDocumentId("1");
$signHere->setPageNumber("1");
$signHere->setRecipientId("1");

   $signHere->AnchorTabItem->AnchorTabString = "#\b";
   $signHere->AnchorTabItem->Unit = "Pixels";
   $signHere->AnchorTabItem->XOffset = 50;
   $signHere->AnchorTabItem->YOffset = 100;
   $signHere->AnchorTabItem->IgnoreIfNotPresent = true;
```

Comment: I don't know how many times i need the signature , Even i don't know the position where i need the signature tab , I just have a placeholder in the html doc and that is #\b . I have to put signature tab where is #\b

Comment: Does you converted doc have the text #\b  or something else? You can try setting IgnoreIfNotPresent=false and see if it throws an error. That would mean the Anchor Text you are looking for is not present in the document.

Comment: I am converting the text into PDF and then adding this pdf text into document  . And yes the text is there in the doc .

Comment: were you able to validate the number of tabs created. You can use the GetTabs API for that.

Comment: @mkd Can you post your HTML?